# Can I use accept() with IOCP?

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, network-programming, iocp

I want to use IOCP to handle hundreds of client connections. Is there's a problem in using `accept()` to accept these connections, or I should use `WSAAccept()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no problem. But there could be, as the berkley and WSA interfaces weren't supposed to be mixed. I mixed sockets and WSASelect in a project with no problem as the `SOCKET` handle given back is the same, regardless of which command you used to obtain it.

But it is IMHO a bad style to mix it where it isn't necessary. So if you already used WSA style, stick to it.

You should also look at the [AcceptEx()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737524.aspx) function.

Answer (score 2):

One very good reason to use `AcceptEx()` is to avoid using another thread which only gets woken up to process new connections.

Be careful with `AcceptEx()` though and, ideally, don't use the "accept and read data" option that's available as that makes it quite easy to DOS the server by opening connections and NOT sending data and the code required to avoid the potential for the DOS attack is quite complex to get right.